# What could cause my Pennco 15045-vf cast iron furnace to not run?

Tags: boiler

My boiler is shutting down into lock out mode, but I don't know what's causing it?

It will start on reset but shut down after a few minutes, but as of now it wont kick on at all.

I checked the pilot and it is on and fine.

I would like to know if this type and model has a flash code to tell what's wrong.

By the vent there is some kind sensor/motor type setup that was making noise and now has stopped altogether.

It' a Pennco 15045vf- Series gas heater.

Comment: that model does not have a draft inducer and pressure sensor

Comment: dont know? its almost soundes like a starter or something.

Comment: it stars before the boiler whould come on. then shuts itself off.. when the boiler kicks in now its not working at all along with the boiler not firing up.

Comment: I am 15yr exp. computer tech/hardware specialist.and can probably fix it.. but i first need to know whats going wrong?

Comment: Does the unit display any error codes?

Comment: i dont know were to find it on this model?

Comment: it has a small front release..panal  were the pilot can be seen but i cant seem to see any other access panel. ill try again to see if i missed one.

Comment: dude thanks so much i called for a hvac tech to come look at it. but in the mean time i was able to get it running. it was a stuck/bad damper. i took it off and gave it a tap and it worked. so i set it to manual so it will stay open until the the tech can come look at it. its a automatic damper. i can change it myself if i can get the part.. but to be on the safe side i wont. thanks again..

Answer (score 1):

## Normal sequence of operation

- Thermostat calls for heat.
- Circulator is activated.
- Water temperature is monitored to determine if thermostat can be satisfied, without firing the burner.

**If the boiler must fire.**

- Damper opens.
- Blocked vent safety switch is closed.
- Gas valve opens.
- Burners ignite.

## Safety switches and limits

#### High limit sensor

If the boiler overheats, this switch will open and the burner will shut down. The burner will remain off until the temperature drops below the high limit setting, the circulator will continue to run until the thermostat is satisfied.

#### Blocked vent safety switch

If this switch is open (vent is closed) the system will shut down, and should not be run until the cause is fixed.

#### Flame rollout switch

If the flame or exhaust gas backs up, this switch will shut the system down.  As with the blocked vent switch, the system should not be run until the cause is fixed.

## Diagnosis

From your description, it sounds like the damper motor is not functioning properly. This causes the blocked vent safety switch to stay open, which does not allow the furnace to fire.  This could be caused by a bad motor, a stuck damper, a malfunctioning switch/sensor elsewhere in the system, or even a bad control board.  You'll have to physically diagnose the system (which can't be done over the internet), or call an HVAC technician to service the unit.

Comment: dude thanks so much i called for a hvac tech to come look at it.

Comment: if im right setting it to manual i will loose about 5% efficiency from my boiler? the only reason im asking is because im gonna be going to school for hvac soon myself.  and i want to learn as much as i can.